# has n, belongs to in Sinatra with DataMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

With the help of an O'Reilly book, I'm building a clone of a url shortening service using Sinatra and DataMapper.  When I test it by submitting a url for shortening, I'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `visits' for nil:NilClass:
```

for line 31. It seems as if Link class doesn't have the visits property, however, as you'll see from the class definitions below, the relationship is such that I should be able to call `link.visits`

I'm using the latest version of DataMapper. Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

```
get '/:short_url' do 
  link = Link.first(:identifier => params[:short_url])
  link.visits << Visit.create(:ip => get_remote_ip(env))   #this is line 32
  link.save
  redirect link.url.original, 301
end
```

**Classes**

```
Class Url
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property  :id,          Serial
  property  :original,    String, :length => 255   
  belongs_to  :link
end

class Link
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property  :identifier,  String, :key => true
  property  :created_at,  DateTime 
  has 1, :url
  has n, :visits


class Visit
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property  :id,          Serial
  property  :created_at,  DateTime
  property  :ip,          IPAddress
  property  :country,     String
  belongs_to  :link

  after :create, :set_country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is where your problem is:

```
link = Link.first(:identifier => params[:short_url])
```

I bet `link` is `nil`

When you get an error like

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `visits' for nil:NilClass:
```

It is saying that you tried to call a method `visits` on the object `nil`. You were expecting to call the method `visits` on a `Link` object.

If you want to find a record if it exists or create a new one, try this:

```
Link.first_or_create(:identifier => params[:short_url])
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to create the new Visit:

```
link.visits.new(:ip => get_remote_ip(env))
link.save
```

Or:

```
Visit.create(:ip => get_remote_ip(env), :visit => visit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that Link doesn't have a visits property. 
The problem is that your line

```
Link.first(:identifier => params[:short_url])
```

is returning nil.

So it's not finding any records that match your search.

To prove this, try doing

```
link = Link.get(1)
```

and you should find a result.